# Bring up squirrelmail using tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat6, squirrelmail

I am trying to bring up squirrelmail using tomcat. I would like know if that is possible at all. This is because i already have tomcat running on that server for my application. Ido not want to start an apache server just for squirrelmail. PLease suggest if there is any documentation on this. I have googled a lot and could not find a solution.

In short my question is how to configure squirrelmail with tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) is what you're looking for.

1. Download the
   [JavaBridgeTemplate621.war](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/download.php)
   file, and drop it into your Tomcat’s webapps directory. If
   `unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"` is set in `conf/server.xml`,
   this file will be unpack automatically.

   Access to `http://domain.com:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate621/test.php` to
   see if it shows your `phpinfo()`.
2. Download
   [SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org/download.php#webmail) to
   `/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/JavaBridgeTemplate621` directory, copy the config
   file `cp config/config_default.php config/config.php` and then browse to
   `http://domain.com:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate621/squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22`.

Good luck.

Comment: I am getting the following exception on the browser. 
java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v] 
 php.java.bridge.Util$Process.start(Util.java:1145)
 php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FCGIProcess.start(FCGIProcess.java:68)
 php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.doBind(SocketChannelFactory.java:125)
 php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory.runFcgi(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:88)
 php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory$1.run(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:109)

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: when you distro you mean PHP/Java bridge?

Comment: I mean the operating system, if Linux, which distribution?

Comment: INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/webapps/javabridge.war
Fatal Error: Failed to start PHP [php-cgi, -v], reason: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "php-cgi" (in directory "/root"): error=2, No such file or directory
Could not start FCGI server: java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v]
Timeout waiting for PHP FastCGI daemon
php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

Comment: i am using ubuntu. uname -a output

Linux 3.2.0-30-virtual #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 17:12:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-cgi` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Each webmail need to 5 things :

1. `MTA  hostname`
2. `MDA port number` such as 143
3. Your `protocol` of course `webmails` uses `imap`.
4. `SMTP hostname`
5. `SMTP port number` such as 25.

Please consider type of authentication , For example , Do you have `SSL, TLS , plain text.`
It's doesn't related to tomcat or apache.

Comment: i guess my question is how to configure squirrelmail with tomcat